# How to manage the width of color boxes

Tags: tcolorbox

I have tried the following code to manage three color boxes, but could not able to arrange properly.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0em}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[2][]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = green!5!white,
   colframe  = green!75!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Huge\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}

\newtcolorbox{BlueBox}[2][]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = blue!5!white,
   colframe  = blue!65!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Large\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}

 \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster valign=center] 

\begin{GreenBox}[width=10cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter]{Objectives 1}

 \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1, raster valign=center] 
  
  \begin{BlueBox}[width=10cm, remember as=box14, nobeforeafter]{Objective 1.1}
  Some text here.
    \end{BlueBox}
  \end{tcbraster}
  \end{GreenBox}
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box2, nobeforeafter]{Objective 2}
Some text here.
\end{GreenBox}
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box3, nobeforeafter]{Objective 3}
Some text here
\end{GreenBox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `standalone` class strictly required? If you use a standard class like `article` and load `\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}` you will get the desired result.

Comment: @Ivan need strictly standalone class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution you need to set the `raster width` explicitly and to use `reset raster` in the second raster to avoid inheriting of the raster width by inner rasters.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

 \newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[2][]{%
 enhanced,
 colback   = green!5!white,
 colframe  = green!75!black, 
 arc       = 4mm, 
 outer arc = 1mm, 
 fonttitle = \Huge\slshape\textbf,
 center title, 
 title     = #2,
 #1}

\newtcolorbox{BlueBox}[2][]{%
 enhanced,
 colback   = blue!5!white,
 colframe  = blue!65!black, 
 arc       = 4mm, 
 outer arc = 1mm, 
 fonttitle = \Large\slshape\textbf,
 center title, 
 title     = #2,
 #1}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{tcbraster}[raster width=18cm,raster columns=3, raster valign=center] 
  
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=10cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter]{Objectives 1}
   
   \begin{tcbraster}[raster reset,raster columns=1, raster valign=center] 
    
    \begin{BlueBox}[width=10cm, remember as=box14, nobeforeafter]{Objective 1.1}
     Some text here.
    \end{BlueBox}
   \end{tcbraster}
  \end{GreenBox}
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box2, nobeforeafter]{Objective 2}
   Some text here.
  \end{GreenBox}
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box3, nobeforeafter]{Objective 3}
   Some text here
  \end{GreenBox}
 \end{tcbraster}
 
\end{document}
```